# Protractor tests are inconsistent even with browser.wait and helper functions

Tags: protractor

I am looking for some advice. I have been using protractor for a few weeks and just cannot get my tests to be consistent unless I use browser.sleep. I have tried helper functions as well as browser.wait(expectedCondition). I have reduced browser.sleep immensely, but protractor still just goes way to fast. I can never successfully run multiple tests unless I have a few browser.sleeps just so protractor can relax for a second. Here is an example: 
**The Test** I need to select a user, delete that user and wait for a success message. Then I click the same user and click the activate button. 
**Outcome:** Unless I have browser.sleep, my success messages do not even appear after deletion/activation. The tests fail because protractor is moving way too fast. Even with the expected conditions. My main problem is that protractor moves to fast for the angular web page. I have tried ifCLickable or isDisplayed but they do not fix the issue entirely. Here is the code:

```
  async deleteUser() {
    await sendClick(this.getNewUser());
    await sendClick(this.getDelete());
    await waitTillPresent(this.getDeleteConfirm());
    await sendClick(this.getDeleteConfirm());
    await waitTillPresent(this.getSuccessMsg())
    expect(await page.getSuccessMsg().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

  }

   async activateUser() {
    await sendClick(this.getNewUser());
    await waitTillPresent(this.getEditBtn())
    await sendClick(this.getActive());
    await waitTillPresent(this.getSuccessMsg())
    expect(await page.getSuccessMsg().isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

  }
```

Functions:

```
  export async function sendClick(element: ElementFinder): Promise<boolean> {
    try { 
      if(!await element.isDisplayed()) {
        return false;
      }
      await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', await element.getWebElement());
      return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }`

export async function waitTillPresent (element: ElementFinder, timeout: number = 10000) {
    return browser.wait(() => {
        return element.isPresent();

    }, timeout);
  }
```

**My Question**: Am I handling this correctly? Is there a better to ensure my tests are consistent? Before these tests, I visit a non-angular webpage. So I have to include the line `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`

Does this mess with the async nature of angular? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked the last few months on our e2e test suite to make it stable. I did not believe it's possible but I made it using correct wait functions and sometimes `browser.sleep()` as a last resort.

You have a correct approach for waiting for elements. But there are 2 problems regarding your implementation:

1) The function `waitTillPresent()` does exactly what its name stands for. But if you only wait until the element is present on the page it does not mean it's clickable or displayed. An element can be hidden and at the same time still be present. Please rename `waitTillPresent()` to `waitTillDisplayed()` and change it as follows:

```
export async function waitTillDisplayed(element: ElementFinder, timeout: number = 20000): Promise<boolean> {
    let result = await browser.wait(() => element.isPresent(), timeout);
    if(!result) {
      return false;
    }
    return await browser.wait(element.isDisplayed(), timeout);
}
```

2) You should exceed the default timeout. Set it a bit higher like 20 to 25 seconds. Just play with it.

Unfortunately, I don't know how `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` changes test behavior. We do not use it :)

#### Note:

These functions are all exactly the same:

```
function foo() { return 'hello world'; }
var foo = () => { return 'hello world'; };
var foo = () => 'hello world';
```

Play with arrow functions, it's syntactic sugar.

Cheers and gl!

Comment: Thank you! I had it working but out of nowhere I am no receiving an error stating `element.isPresent is not a function`. This worked before, not too sure what happened...

Comment: Well, that's something strange. I don't know why this error would occur since we are using Types...
You could remove the `element.isPresent()` and only use `element.isDisplayed()` for waiting. I Think `isDisplayed()` also checks if it's present.

Comment: Yes, this solution fixed my issue. strange... but thank you.